# Entity Framework loading sub collection

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to fill a Rights object in my PersonRight object using the following code:

```
var results = (from P in this.ObjectContext.Person
                join R in this.ObjectContext.Rights
                 on R.personid = p.personid
                select new PersonRight(){
                               Name = P.Name,
                           }).AsQueryable();



public class PersonRight
{
    public property Person { get; set; }
    public List<Rights> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to populate the Rights object with this query, how can this be done? I can not use entity framework created entity so I need to fill these database objects into a custom type.

Thank you

Comment: your question isn't very clear (for example: PersonRight class doesn't define a "Name" property!). What exactly would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var results = (from P in this.ObjectContext.Person
               join R in this.ObjectContext.Rights
               on P.personid equals R.personid
               into PR
               select new PersonRight()
               {
                   Name = P.Name,
                   Rights = PR
               }).AsQueryable();

public class PersonRight
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rights> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

A few things to notice:

- You **must** use `equals` in LINQ `join` and not `==`.
- On the left side of `equals` **must** be the outer variable, so `on R.personid equals P.personid` is wrong.
- You must use the `into` keyword to create a group of all rights for a particular person. The variable `PR` represents an IEnumerable of all rights of the person.
- I don't know how to get this working if `Rights` in your `PersonRight` class is a `List<Rights>`. Using `PR.ToList()` is not possible in LINQ to Entities because it will complain that it cannot translate `ToList()` to a store expression.
- This all assumes that you don't have a navigation property on your Person class which points directly to the rights (like `Person.Rights`). If you have it you should leverage it in your query and don't use `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = (from P in this.ObjectContext.Person                 
                select new PersonRight()
                           {Person = P,
                            Rights = p.Rights.ToList() }).ToList();
```

OR

```
var results = (from P in this.ObjectContext.Person                 
                select new PersonRight()
                           {Person = P,
                            Rights = this.ObjectContext.Rights.Where(r=>r.personid == p.personid ).ToList() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (maybe not very effective?) is to simply get list of `Persons` and in creation of each `PersonRights` object, get corresponding `Rights`:

```
var results = 
    (from P in this.ObjectContext.Person
     select new PersonRight 
     {
        Name = P.Name,
        Rights = (from R in this.ObjectContext.Rights where R.personid == P.personid select R).ToList()
     }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: When i tested the AsQueryable did not enumerate until called.  The ToList method enumerates and is still queriable with linq to objects.

Comment: @Chad: that's the purpose of it. :)